# Как преобразовать дату из первой строки?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, обработка-данных

Как преобразовать дату в `'2010-07-17'`?

```
data['Date'][0:1]
0   2010-07-17
Name: Date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь методом [Series.dt.strftime()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

Пример:

```
In [93]: df
Out[93]:
        Date
0 2010-07-17
1 2012-02-29

In [94]: df.dtypes
Out[94]:
Date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object

In [95]: df["dt_str"] = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

In [96]: df
Out[96]:
        Date      dt_str
0 2010-07-17  2010-07-17
1 2012-02-29  2012-02-29

In [97]: df.dtypes
Out[97]:
Date      datetime64[ns]
dt_str            object    #   <--- NOTE !
dtype: object
```

---

**UPD:** Чтобы получить одно значение столбца с датой в виде текста:

```
In [98]: res = df["Date"].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d").at[0]

In [99]: res
Out[99]: '2010-07-17'
```

---

PS атрибут доступа [Series.at[XYZ]](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.at.html) возвращает значение ряда из строки со значением индекса (`label`) = `XYZ`, для того чтобы извлечь значение ряда по его порядковому номеру (нумерация начинается с нуля) вне зависимости от значений индекса нужно воспользоваться атрибутом [Series.iat[N]](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.iat.html).

Пример:

```
In [100]: s = pd.Series([11,12,13], index=list("abc"))

In [101]: s
Out[101]:
a    11
b    12
c    13
dtype: int64

In [102]: s.at["b"]
Out[102]: 12

In [103]: s.iat[1]
Out[103]: 12
```